# How to pick an item from an array and keep on cycling through by using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I actually want to pick an item from the array (A or B or C) and display it in a block. Then changes at 2 second interval and keep on cycling through.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var arr = ["A","B","C"];
        setInterval(function ChangeText() {
            var span = document.getElementById("spnChanger")
            var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
            span.innerHTML = arr[i]
        }, 2000);
</script>
```

- Such as if A is randomly picked, A will be shown at first, followed by B and C and then back to A and loop endlessly
- Such as if B is randomly picked, B will be shown at first, followed by C and A and then back to B and loop endlessly
- Such as if C is randomly picked, C will be shown at first, followed by A and B and then back to C and loop endlessly

But all i can get is a random item from the array every time which cannot continuously go through the cycle.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Move the random outside the interval, and instead use the interval to increment & mod the index and update the DOM.

Comment: @tehhowch Could you please show me how it will be like? I am just a beginner of Javascript so i really need a clear answer. Thanks!

Comment: Were any of these answers satisfactory? If so, please mark one with an accepted checkmark and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely condense this a bit, but I left separate lines so you can more easily see what's going on;

```
var arr = ["A", "B", "C"];
var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); //initialize the index
var span = document.getElementById("spnChanger"); //this isn't changing, so you can look it up outside of the timer
setInterval(() => {
  span.innerHTML = arr[idx];
  idx++;
  idx %= 3; //this is the mod based on the length of arr, this handles wrapping to the start
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna use randojs.com to answer your question, so if you'd like to use my code, copy and paste this into the head tag in your HTML document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

And then you can use this nice short code:

```
var arr = ["A", "B", "C"];
var index = rando(arr).index;
setInterval(function(){
    if(arr.length > 0){
        document.getElementById("spnChanger").innerHTML = arr[index++ % arr.length];
    }
}, 2000);
```

It doesn't matter how many items are in your array. This code will account for it automatically.